# Adding month to DateType based on column value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming a dataframe with a date column and an Int column representing a number of months:

```
val df = Seq(("2011-11-11",1),("2010-11-11",3),("2012-11-11",5))
              .toDF("startDate","monthsToAdd")
              .withColumn("startDate",'startDate.cast(DateType))

+----------+-----------+
| startDate|monthsToAdd|
+----------+-----------+
|2011-11-11|          1|
|2010-11-11|          3|
|2012-11-11|          5|
+----------+-----------+
```

is there a way of creating an endDate column by adding the months to startDate without converting the date column back to string?

So basically same as the add_months function

```
def add_months(startDate: Column, numMonths: Int)
```

but passing a column instead of a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **`UDF (User Defined Functions)`** to achieve this. Below I have create `myUDF` function which add the months to date and returns the result date in String format and I will use this UDF to create a new column by using `withColumn` on `DataFrame`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(("2011-11-11",1),("2010-11-11",3),("2012-11-11",5)).toDF("startDate","monthsToAdd")

val myUDF = udf {
  val simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  (startDate: String, monthValue: Int) => {
    val calendar = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(startDate)
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthValue)
    simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime)
  }
}

val newDf = df.withColumn("endDate", myUDF(df("startDate"), df("monthsToAdd")))
newDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| startDate|monthsToAdd|   endDate|
+----------+-----------+----------+
|2011-11-11|          1|2011-12-11|
|2010-11-11|          3|2011-02-11|
|2012-11-11|          5|2013-04-11|
+----------+-----------+----------+
```